# Entity Framework connections in loops

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parallel-processing

I have a list of integers called IDsList, which is used to extract a list of XML strings from a table called MyTbl using an entity framework connection.  The XML strings are then used to perform other tasks.  Which of the following would be better?

Method 1

```
var IDsList = new List<Int32> () {17, 23, 47, 62, 63, 79, 85, 91, 100}; // user input
List<String> XMLStrs = null;
using (var ctx = new DatabaseEntities ()) {
    XMLStrs = IDsList.Select (i => Ctx.MyTbl.First (tr => tr.id == i).xml_str).ToList ();
}
XMLStrs.AsParallel ().ForAll (xs => {
    // Do something in parallel
});
```

Method 2

```
var IDsList = new List<Int32> () {17, 23, 47, 62, 63, 79, 85, 91, 100}; // user input
IDsList.AsParallel ().ForAll (i => {
    using (var ctx = new DatabaseEntities ()) {
        var xs = ctx.MyTTbl.First (tr => tr.id == i).xml_str;
        // Do something with xs
    }
});
```

Or is there a different method that is more idiomatic C#?

**Please note** that IDsList is generally a much longer list, often several thousands in length.  And each separate execution on a particular value of xs takes roughly the same amount of time as any other.

Comment: You should note that depending on the affinity of the machine and your Process, Method #2 could create a very large amount of database connections, essentially triggering a DOS filter in some networks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the rows which have an ID that exists in the IDsList, with EF 4.1, you can use .Contains in your queries:

```
var IDsList = new []{17, 23, 47, 62, 63, 79, 85, 91, 100}; // user input
List<string> XMLStrs = null;
using (var ctx = new DatabaseEntities()) 
{
    XMLStrs = (from tr in Ctx.MyTbl
               where IDsList.Contains(tr.id)
               select tr.xml_str).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Read his question again, his code examples specifically indicate the problem is getting rows from a database specified by an integer value in his list "IDsList".

Comment: No...the question involves matching against a *very large list* of ID values. Hence the parallel processing. Although using `Contains()` is the proper way to translate to `IN` in SQL, the real issue is which method of using PLINQ to prefer.

Comment: Read the title of the question though, it's in reference to EF, not PLINQ.

Comment: The question is tagged with `parallel`.

Comment: So if I ask a question about javascript and tag it with c#, it's most obviously in regards to c# then?